# What is this formula for matrix elements called?

Tags: matrices

In a solution from a physics problem, the author uses (for $M$ a 3x3 matrix) that
$$M_{33} = \frac{|M_\perp^{-1}|}{|M^{-1}|}$$
where $M_\perp^{-1}$ is the upper 2x2 block of $M^{-1}$. This bears a vague resemblance to Cramer's rule but I'm not sure? It also seems like a Laplace expansion rearranged, but other terms are missing? The presence of the inverses is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinental formula for the inverse of a matrix (closely related to Cramer's rule) is

$$ A^{-1}_{ji} = (-1)^{i+j} \frac{\det(A \text{ with the $i$th row + $j$th column deleted)}}{\det A}. $$

*Notice that's $A^{-1}_{ji}$ not $A^{-1}_{ij}$.

For $i = j = 3$ you get exactly your formula but with $A$ and $A^{-1}$ trading places which is justified because $A$ is the inverse of $A^{-1}$.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: Superb, thank you so much!